# In Twilio, what are "monitor-reads" and "monitor-writes"?

Tags: twilio

This morning I saw two event triggers in my account that I never saw before, and don't think were there last night. I don't know what they mean. I'm sure the words have meaning to the people at Twilio, but clicking help on Twilio brings me to stack overflow. The https://www.twilio.com/console/usage/triggers page shows the following:

```
FRIENDLY NAME   USAGE CATEGORY  CURRENT VALUE   TRIGGER VALUE   FREQUENCY   LAST FIRED 
Nearing monitor-reads free tier (5000). Consumed 4000   monitor-reads   0   4,000.00        ---
Nearing monitor-writes free tier (10000). Consumed 8000 monitor-writes  0   8,000.00        ---
```

Clicking on the event gives me no idea what it's talking about either.

```
CURRENT VALUE
0

LAST FIRED
Never 

USAGE CATEGORY
monitor: reads

TRIGGER VALUE
4,000.00

TRIGGER BY
count
```

I search the words in Twilio to see what that means and found [this](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135767-Audit-Monitor-Events-charges-in-your-Twilio-project) but I still have no idea what it means either. Hoping one of the Twilio support people see this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `monitor-reads` and `monitor-writes` events refer to the Audit Events that you can have switched on for your account. The help article you linked to is actually out of date, particularly where it says everyone is opted in automatically (and I am working to get the article updated).

A better [description of Audit Events comes from this page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/224592307-Opting-out-of-Audit-Monitor-Events), which says:

> Audit Events (previously known as Monitor Events) is designed to give Information Technology (IT)  and Information Security (Info-Sec) teams detailed operational insight into their Twilio utilization. This feature is most beneficial to those with IT compliance and security requirements - eg storing detailed change logs for forensic analysis and security reviews. However, this feature is not beneficial, or needed, by most of Twilio’s customers.
>
> If you need to track configuration changes within your Twilio project because of security and compliance requirements, please opt-in to Audit Events. Note that you will be charged for Audit Events written, stored, and read via the API.

I've also discovered that we do generate the triggers that you are seeing, even if you are not opted in. We are working to change that and avoid this confusion in the future.

All you need to know is that you are not automatically opted in to Audit Events and those triggers will not affect you unless you decide to opt into Audit Events in the future.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for finding my question and posting an answer. Your answer and the documentation I found and linked to in my question both seem to indicate that I would be charged for something I still don't know what is. What's more is how could I have over 8000 monitor writes when I haven't had even close to a thousand calls, faxes and texts combined? If there are so many monitor/audit events, why can't I see them?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you are not opted in to Audit Events (unless, when you are logged in you can access this page: https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/audit-events) so you will not be charged for anything and those numbers don't matter. If it turns out that you are opted in, you can cancel it there in the admin or get in touch with Twilio support to cancel.

Comment: `twilio.com/console/runtime/audit-events 
Access to restricted content is not permissible.` so hopefully it won't matter. Thanks again.

Comment: It will not matter! If you do ever want the audit events though, do get in touch! :D